# Set 2 styles on notification - MediaStyle() and BigTextStyle()

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to have a notification with play/pause action, also a text that shows the song name, so in order to see the full name I need BigTextStyle.

Is there a way to add 2 styles to notificationBuilder ?

```
 .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1))
```

and

```
 .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(currentSongName))
```

If it's not possible I'm going with custom layout.
Thanks in advance.